# How to specify the presence or non-presence of white space in scala parser combinators?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

Let's say I have the following:

```
case class Var(s: String)

class MyParser extends JavaTokensParser {

  def variableExpr = "?" ~ identifier ^^ { case "?" ~ id => Var(id) }

  def identifier = //...

}
```

I want this to accept inputs of the form `?X` but not `? X` (with a space in between). How would this be expressed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JavaTokensParser` by default allows white spaces between any parsers. You could change this behavior this way:

```
override def skipWhitespace = false
```

Now you have to specify all white spaces manually:

```
def ws: Parser[Seq[Char]] = rep(' ')

def variableExpr = ws ~> "?" ~ identifier ^^ { case "?" ~ id => Var(id) }
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any predefined parser that accepts any whitespace?

Comment: Second question: is there a more appropriate class than ``JavaTokensParser`` that I should consider using?

Comment: @Gonzalo: `"""\s+""".r` [is used in scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/RegexParsers.scala#L60).